# If Jesus was God (The Famous John 1:1), Why was He exalted to higher position (as if he wasn't in that position)?

Tags: trinity, non-trinitarian

I was a Trinitarian until I discussed it with a JW. I still believe in the Trinity because there're many verses to back this up (including Matt. 28:19). But I wondered.

According to Phil 2:9 and some other verses, Jesus was exalted. If He was/is God, why after the resurrection was He not only resurrected but also exalted to a higher position (as if he wasn't in that position)?

Edit :
I meant God the Father exalted Jesus to be on the right hand after His obedience as if He was an angel (Michael Arcangel) before then now be the firstborn aka the heir of the authorities and kingdom of His Father.